# How much data does windows write on boot

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot

This question was inspired by Bob's comment to my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/437851/82812).

On boot, windows writes files to the hard drive (I imagine this to be the case, as it has a way of detecting if the boot was previously interrupted by a hard power-off, and I am sure many other things).

But assuming that there is a "smooth" boot, where there are no error, etc, and no logon scripts that run, and things like that, about how much (a few KB, a few MB, a few GB) data gets written to the drive?

For simplicity's sake, assume that:

- hibernation is turned off
- windows 7
- pagefile is turned off (does this matter right at boot, or only later?)

How could one go about measuring this? Are there resources that have this information?

Comment: I don't have a exact number for a answer (and I don't know if it will be KB or GB) so I will leave this as a comment. You could create a VM with your parameters and track inside the host OS the total data written to the container that represents the hard drive in whatever VM software you are using.

Comment: Good idea, just lacking the windows VM part. Hopefully someone else will come along that can do that.

Comment: It's not necessarily the amount of new data written (i.e. overall size change) when in the context of deleted data recovery; any data that's *overwritten* (i.e. including deleted and then rewritten) has the potential to overwrite 'deleted' data.

Comment: right, but unless there is a way to know definitively where the written data will go, best to take a worst case scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [WinBootInfo](http://www.clockmod.com/index.php?/products/view/winbootinfo_1.0/). According to them,

> WinBootInfo is the advanced Windows Boot Analyzer that logs drivers
>   and applications loaded during system boot, measures Windows boot
>   times, records CPU and I/O activity during the boot, and much more!

Looking at [a screenshot](http://www.techmaish.com/winbootinfo-advance-windows-boot-analyzer-for-windows-7-and-vista/), there is a field called "Total I/O Data Write" (showing a few MBs in the screenshot)

Or try [hIOmon](http://www.hyperio.com/hIOmon/hIOmonBigPicture.htm). See [Boot Logging Support](http://www.hyperio.com/hIOmon/hIOmon.htm#BootLogging).